# Deploying code changes to IoT devices without direct access to it

Tags: iot, continuous-deployment

I'm wondering what is the best way to keep continuous deployment on IoT machines (connected to the internet), but without direct access to it. The codebase is in Go; is it better to write my own agent which will check some endpoint for a new code package/repository, or is there a software (or SaaS) that solves that kind of problem already?

PS. IoT machines runs under Debian 9.x.

Comment: Can you write your firmware on the machine in such a way to poll the base server periodically asking for the current version, then pulling an update if it differs from the current version?

Comment: @RobertHowe of course I can (and I am considering that approach), but want to know if is a better way (eg. orchestration software, async queues etc). I would like to read the experience of people who have already done it :-)